# Android, DialogModal add FragmentContainerView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, modal-dialog

I have a ModalReplenishment.class I call it from BillingsListOneFragment.class using the following method

```
private void handlerBtnReplenishment(Billings bill){
    ModalReplenishment modalReplenishment = new ModalReplenishment(getContext(),bill);
    modalReplenishment.modalStart(new DialogCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception exception) {

        }
    });

}
```

full code ModalReplenishment.class

```
public class ModalReplenishment implements DialogModal{
    private ImageView imageViewBillingCard;
    private TextView tVNameBilling, tVABillingBalance, tVTypeCurrency, tVTypeBilling;
    private ToggleButton toggleBtnIncome, toggleBtnTheBill;
    private Billings billing;
    private Context context;
    private Dialog dialogModal;

    public ModalReplenishment(Context context, Billings billing) {
        this.context = context;
        this.billing = billing;
    }

    @Override
    public void modalStart(DialogCallback dialogCallback) {
        showDialogModal();
        setupUIDialogModal();
        setValueObjectModal();
        handlerButtonDialogModal(dialogCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void showDialogModal() {
        dialogModal = new Dialog(context);
        dialogModal.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialogModal.setContentView(R.layout.modal_bottom_replenishment);
        dialogModal.show();
        dialogModal.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialogModal.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialogModal.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
        dialogModal.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

    }

    @Override
    public void setupUIDialogModal() {
        this.toggleBtnIncome = dialogModal.findViewById(R.id.toggleBtnIncome);
        this.toggleBtnTheBill = dialogModal.findViewById(R.id.toggleBtnTheBill);
        this.imageViewBillingCard = dialogModal.findViewById(R.id.imageView_modal_account_card);
        this.tVNameBilling = dialogModal.findViewById(R.id.textView_modal_name_account);
        this.tVABillingBalance = dialogModal.findViewById(R.id.textView_modal_balance_account);
        this.tVTypeCurrency = dialogModal.findViewById(R.id.textView_modal_type_currency);
        this.tVTypeBilling = dialogModal.findViewById(R.id.textView_type_account);
    }

    @Override
    public void handlerButtonDialogModal(DialogCallback dialogCallback) {
        handlerToggleButton();
    }

    private void handlerToggleButton(){
        toggleBtnIncome.setOnClickListener(v->{
            switcherToggleButton(toggleBtnIncome);
        });
        toggleBtnTheBill.setOnClickListener(v->{
            switcherToggleButton(toggleBtnTheBill);
        });
    }

    private void switcherToggleButton(ToggleButton toggleButton) {
        if(toggleBtnIncome == toggleButton){
            toggleBtnTheBill.setChecked(false);
            toggleBtnTheBill.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.gray));
            toggleBtnIncome.setChecked(true);
            toggleBtnIncome.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
            showFragReplenishment();
        }
        if(toggleBtnTheBill == toggleButton){
            toggleBtnIncome.setChecked(false);
            toggleBtnIncome.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.gray));
            toggleBtnTheBill.setChecked(true);
            toggleBtnTheBill.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
            showFragReplenishment();
        }
    }

    private void setValueObjectModal() {
        switcherToggleButton(toggleBtnIncome);
        imageViewBillingCard.setImageResource(TypeBillings.getIdImageTypeBillings(billing.getTypeBillings()));
        tVNameBilling.setText(billing.getName());
        tVABillingBalance.setText(String.valueOf(billing.getBalance()));
        tVTypeCurrency.setText(billing.getTypeCurrency());
        tVTypeBilling.setText(billing.getTypeBillings());
    }

    private void showFragReplenishment() {
        Fragment selectedFragment;
        if (toggleBtnIncome.isChecked()) {
            selectedFragment = new IncomeFragment(); // Створіть фрагмент для доходів
        } else {
            selectedFragment = new TheBillFragment(); // Створіть фрагмент для рахунку
        }

        FragmentTransaction transaction = ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragContainerReplenishment, selectedFragment); // Оновіть ідентифікатор на fragContainerReplenishment
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

when I already call showFragReplenishment() I get an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080294 (com.example.monefy:id/fragContainerReplenishment) for fragment IncomeFragment{e69585f} (15d3592f-20d2-4b93-8549-823b43dd61e9 id=0x7f080294)
                    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:513)
```

id  element correct FragmentContainerView @+id/fragContainerReplenishment

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/fragContainerReplenishment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>
```

I need that when I showFragReplenishment(), the content of the fragments is loaded accordingly.